# Draggable Jquery timetable/timeline for reservations

Tags: jquery, timeline, timetable

I'm searching for a plugin/code to realize a draggable jquery timetable or timeline to manage reservations, stored in an SQL database. Reservations (so the rows) should be draggable to change room location, change reservation dates and so on.

Here it is a scratch of what I mean:
[image]

Searching on internet, I found lots of calendar plugin, like Fullcalendar, but they doesn't look good for me.
The following items should be perfect for me, but all of them is not free.

- [Full calendar timetable](http://fullcalendar.io/timeline/)
- [DHTMLX](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/)
- [Daypilot](http://www.daypilot.org/)

  ***Does anyone know a similar plugin for FREE?***